# Child routing in Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I try to implement child route in my ng2-app. After starting app i get exception **"Component "AppComponent" has no route config."**
Here is my code below:

**main.ts:**

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/forms";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {AuthenticationService} from "./authentication/authentication.service";
import {provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
import {routes} from "./app.routes";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provideRouter(routes),
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    FORM_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    AuthenticationService
]);
```

**app.routes.ts:**

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService]},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService], children: [
        {path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent},
        {path: 'second-component', component: SecondComponent}
    ]},
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService]}
];
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public router:Router) {
    }
}
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {SidebarComponent} from "./sidebar/sidebar.component";
import {HeaderComponent} from "./header/header.component";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: 'trinjer-home',
    template: `
        <header></header>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [SidebarComponent, HeaderComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }
}
```

Can't understand, what i do wrong, how to configure this child routing inside home.component?
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to your first route (with the empty path `''`)

Comment: Anyway, i get 'ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component "AppComponent" has no route config.' error.

Comment: Your `HomeComponent`(path `''`) has a `<router-outlet>` but no child routes. AFAIK this is not supported. Perhaps you want to use `redirectTo: '/home'` instead of `component: HomeComponent` for this route?

Comment: `export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService], children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
        {path: 'milestones', component: MilestonesComponent}
    ]},
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService]}
];`

Comment: Now i have such config, but error is same

Comment: Have you tried without the `**` route? (could also be changed to a redirect to home). I don't see any more problems. Maybe a Plunker to reproduce might help.

Comment: I've removed `**` route, and now i get `Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'SecondComponent'`

Comment: You get this error when you load the app with an empty route path? This means it should match the first route, redirect to `'home'` then find the child route with empty path there, redirect to `'second-component'`. Right?

Comment: Yes, with empty. I want to implement such logic:
If i'm not logged in my AuthenticationService redirects me on login page(first route).
If i'm logged in, it should show me header component, sidebar component with navigation and children components due to my second route

Comment: A Plunker to reproduce would be helpful. Are you using the latest router version (at least beta.2)

Comment: Yes, RC4.
Yeah, will try to make Plunker, just give me some time :)

Comment: Uploaded on google drive:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5JhzhZuKocUV2JTWHpTS25zNFk

Comment: That is not very helpful. Please create a Plunker.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/6s5J62vh4fcGzPQDSOiW?p=preview

Comment: But it can't even run

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html as a template.

Comment: Thanks, a little bit better)
http://plnkr.co/edit/Jv7oGHEvtQKqBEHLbpQq?p=preview
But now I'm facing with this trouble: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'xyDD8bn3q5sLArXa'**

Comment: Solved by replacing default route by this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set one of the children as a defalut for the parent component by setting the path as an empty string

```
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService], children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'first-component', 
    {path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent},
    {path: 'second-component', component: SecondComponent}
]},
```

check this from the official documentation

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Also check this tutorial it might help you understand it more

> http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Comment: `export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationService], children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
        {path: 'milestones', component: MilestonesComponent}
    ]}
];`
Now I have such config, and get **Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'SecondComponent'**