# parent-child routing in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

when I perform routing in angular I got an error like `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'example2/child1'`here i define routes in `app.module.ts`

```
{ path:"for", component: ForComponent },
      { path:"example1", component: Example1Component },
      { path:"example2",component: Example2Component ,
          children: [          
          { path:"child1",component:Child1Component },
          { path:"child2",component:Child2Component },
          { path:"child3",component:Child3Component }
          ]
      }
```

in my parent component i set dynamic link to navigate child component

```
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of coutry">
         <a href="" routerLink="{{item.name}}" >{{item.name}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

so what I do? also, see the same question in StackOverflow but didn't work[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875592/child-routing-in-angular-2-application)

Answer (score 2):

How can it match `india` when there is no `india` as path in your `children` array. You need that, or a parameter path like `path:":country"`:

So solution 1:

```
{ path:"example2",component: Example2Component ,
  children: [          
    { path:"india",component:Child1Component },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

or with parameter path:

```
{ path:"example2",component: Example2Component ,
  children: [          
    { path:":country",component:Child1Component },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: and one more thing in  the second solution you write `:` before name of parameter what exactly meaning of this?

Comment: it's worked perfect but with this, I want to perform a task like a click on the particular link it navigates to another page and shows details but now it's open on the same page.Please help

Answer (score 1):

you have not entered the path resolution on the children of 'example2':

```
{ path:"for", component: ForComponent },
      { path:"example1", component: Example1Component },
      { path:"example2",component: Example2Component ,
          children: [          
          { path:"india",component:Child1Component },
          { path:"child2",component:Child2Component },
          { path:"child3",component:Child3Component }
          ]
      }
```